# Using Android studio and my application force closes when i click a button

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi I'm making a bill splitting app in android studio 3.3. I've made a database with sqlite and it stores a product's name and cost. As I am trying to get the total cost of the input from the database and store it in a text view the app closes. I've came to the conclusion that the problem is located in the `getTotal()` method in `MyDBHandler.java`

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";
    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTCOST = "productcost";


    //We need to pass database information along to superclass
    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, 
    SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " + "," +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTCOST + " INTEGER " +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    //Add a new row to the database
    public void addProduct(Products product){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTCOST, product.get_productcost());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    //Delete a product from the database
    public void deleteProduct(String productName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + 
    COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "\";");
    }

    //get the total sum of teh Product_Cost column
    //
    //  TODO: fix this method to display total
    //  NOTE: THIS IS YOUR PROBLEM
    //
    //
    public int GetTotal(){
        int temp;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = " SELECT SUM(COLUMN_PRODUCTCOST) FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + ";";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            temp = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        else return 0;

        cursor.close();


        return temp;
    }


    // converts the elements in the database to a string so you can print the database out.
    public String databaseToString(){
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";// why not leave out the WHERE  clause?

        //Cursor points to a location in your results
        Cursor recordSet = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //Move to the first row in your results
        recordSet.moveToFirst();

        //Position after the last row means the end of the results
        while (!recordSet.isAfterLast()) {
            // null could happen if we used our empty constructor
            if (recordSet.getString(recordSet.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
                dbString += recordSet.getString(recordSet.getColumnIndex("productname"));
                dbString += "\t $";
                dbString += recordSet.getString(recordSet.getColumnIndex("productcost"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
            recordSet.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }

}



  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText userInput;
        EditText userInputC;
        TextView recordsTextView;
        TextView Results;
        MyDBHandler dbHandler;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_Input);
            userInputC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_InputC);
            recordsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.records_TextView);
            Results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Results);
            /* Can pass nulls because of the constants in the helper.
             * the 1 means version 1 so don't run update.
             */
            dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
            printDatabase();
        }

        //Print the database
        public void printDatabase(){
            String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
            recordsTextView.setText(dbString);
            userInput.setText("");
            userInputC.setText("");
        }

        /*
        //Add a product to the database
        public void addButtonClicked(View view){
            // dbHandler.add needs an object parameter.
            int count = Integer.parseInt(Results.getText().toString());
            int num = Integer.parseInt(userInputC.getText().toString());
            count = count + num;

            String temp = Results.getText().toString();
            float temp1 = Float.parseFloat(temp);

            //Results.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            Results.setText(Float.toString(count));

            Products product = new Products(userInput.getText().toString(), temp1);
            dbHandler.addProduct(product);

            //Results = ;
            printDatabase();


        }*/

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void addButtonClicked(View view){
        // dbHandler.add needs an object parameter.
        int usersinput = Integer.parseInt(userInputC.getText().toString());
        Products product = new Products(userInput.getText().toString(), usersinput);
        int temp = dbHandler.GetTotal();
        dbHandler.addProduct(product);
        Results.setText(Integer.toString(temp));
        printDatabase();


    }

        //Delete items
        public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){


            // dbHandler delete needs string to find in the db
            String inputText = userInput.getText().toString();
            dbHandler.deleteProduct(inputText);
            printDatabase();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you look into Room Persistence Library by Google, which is the newly introduced and better way to interact with your SQLite DB. Look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKWh4ckvFPM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change :-

```
String query = " SELECT SUM(COLUMN_PRODUCTCOST) FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + ";";
```

to be

```
String query = " SELECT SUM(" + COLUMN_PRODUCTCOST + ") FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + ";";
```

Otherwise the query will fail as there is no column named **COLUMN_PRODUCTCOST**, instead you want the value when **COLUMN_PRODUCTCOST** is resolved (i.e. **productcost**), which is a column name.

You may also wish to consider using the [**query**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) convenience method rather than using the **rawQuery** method.

Your code could then be :-

```
public int GetTotal(){
    int temp;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{"SELECT SUM(" + COLUMN_PRODUCTCOST + ")"}
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCTS,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        temp = cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    else temp = 0; //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED not to return as the Cursor would not be closed.
    cursor.close();
    return temp;
}
```

- Note this closes the Cursor even if there are no rows, which should be the case (*you could apply this to your code that uses rawQuery*).

Comment: @TavisHicks note the edit and closing the Cursor (could/should be applied to rawQuery if you stick with that), as even a Cursor with no rows should be closed).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad sql query:

```
String query = " SELECT SUM(COLUMN_PRODUCTCOST) FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + ";"
```

Should it be

```
String query = " SELECT SUM(" + COLUMN_PRODUCTCOST + ") FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + ";"
```